# how to post data to an ajax function with Jsoup

Tags: java, ajax, parsing, jsoup

i want to post a string to

```
<li id="coz"><a
        onclick="doRequest('zemberek.jsp','YAZI_COZUMLE');">Cozumle</a></li>
```

by Jsoup?.How can I do?
here is original site : http://zemberek-web.appspot.com/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function doRequest(url, islem) {
            var ajaxRequest = new AjaxRequest(url);
            var hiddenField = document.getElementById("islem");
            hiddenField.value = islem;
            ajaxRequest.addNamedFormElements("giris", "islem");
            ajaxRequest.sendRequest();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<big>Zemberek Demo</big>
<small>(<a href="http://code.google.com/p/zemberek">Zemberek
Proje Sitesi</a>)</small>
<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="denetle"><a
        onclick="doRequest('zemberek.jsp', 'YAZI_DENETLE');">Denetle</a></li>
    <li id="coz"><a
        onclick="doRequest('zemberek.jsp','YAZI_COZUMLE');">Cozumle</a></li>
    <li id="oner"><a onclick="doRequest('zemberek.jsp','ONER');">Oner</a></li>
    <li id="ascii2tr"><a
        onclick="doRequest('zemberek.jsp','ASCII_TURKCE');">Ascii->Tr</a></li>
    <li id="tr2ascii"><a
        onclick="doRequest('zemberek.jsp','TURKCE_ASCII');">Tr->ascii</a></li>
    <li id="hecele"><a onclick="doRequest('zemberek.jsp','HECELE');">Hecele</a></li>
    <li id="ayristir"><a
        onclick="doRequest('zemberek.jsp','SACMALA');">Sacmala</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<form id="form" action="#">
<P align=center><b>Islem yapilacak yaziyi asagidaki alana
giriniz.</b><br>
<textarea name="giris" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea> <input
    type="hidden" name="islem" id="islem" /></P>
</form>

<br>

<div id="div"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and working solution with Jsoup:

**Code**

```
String url = "http://zemberek-web.appspot.com/zemberek.jsp?ts=1367326940830&giris=%s&islem=YAZI_COZUMLE";

String query = "MyParamĄĘÓŚŁ";

String formattedUrl = String.format(url, URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"));

Document document = Jsoup.connect(formattedUrl).get();

String result = document.select("taconite-root > taconite-replace-children > div").text();

System.out.println(result);
```

**Result**

```
MyParam :cozulemedi
```

Comment: Thank you that is work.So but I cannot getResult for some words because of UTF-8.How can i deal it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the anserw is the following if you look the request in Google Chrome developper tools you will see that when you click the generated url is the following for example :

```
http://zemberek-web.appspot.com/zemberek.jsp?ts=1367076182039&giris=bnfhjfttgfhffgfg&islem=ASCII_TURKCE
```

giris=bnfhjfttgfhffgfg => is your string sent to the server.

So you can do in every programming language this following

```
http://zemberek-web.appspot.com/zemberek.jsp?ts=1367076182039&giris=MY_STRING&islem=ASCII_TURKCE
```

Don't forget to UTF-8 encode your string for the query string

**UPDATE**

Here is an example that I've made

```
public class MyRequester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        InputStream in = null;

        try {


            String textToSend = "Java is cool :)";
            String urlRequest = "http://zemberek-web.appspot.com/zemberek.jsp?ts=1367076182039&giris="+URLEncoder.encode(textToSend, "UTF-8")+"&islem=ASCII_TURKCE";

            System.out.println(urlRequest+"\n");

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlRequest).openConnection();
            in = conn.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String data = null;

            while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(data);
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            if(conn != null){
                conn.disconnect();
            }

            if(in != null){
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }



    }

}
```

Output in the console :

```
http://zemberek-web.appspot.com/zemberek.jsp?ts=1367076182039&giris=Java+is+cool+%3A%29&islem=ASCII_TURKCE

<taconite-root> <taconite-replace-children  contextNodeID="div" parseInBrowser="true"><div> Java <font color="#33AA33">iÅŸ</font> <font color="#FF0033">cool</font> :) </div> </taconite-replace-children> </taconite-root>
```

The result from the request is a XML document. According to my experience I would use SAX instead of Java XML native implementation.

Comment: How do I get result of posted string with this url?

Comment: I've made an example who show how to do that. You just have to use the  URL class that provides an inputstream from the request made. In fact the inputstream is all the element send back to the browser. So you can do what you want after that